# Changing UIPickerView row height

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I'm working on a program for a class I'm taking and part of the program requires a `UIPickerView` with images in it. I have the picker up and running, but the height of the rows in the picker are still too small, causing the images (100x100) to overlap. I'm looking for a way to change the `UIPickerView` so that the images will fit in one row, without overlapping. Thanks

Comment: UIPickerView rowSizeForComponent: method ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the documentation for the [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIPickerView), you have a link to the [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html) protocol.  There is a method that you can implement, `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, but I never knew the method name. Thank you!

Comment: @Paul Woidke : try to double click a Class name , Protocol (in this case the `<UIPickerViewDelegate>`) with the command key pressed.  
It will send you to the appropriate H file.
Command + Option + double click : will open it in the assistant editor (XCode 4 and above..)

Answer (score 24):

use this method,provide default as a delegete method.

**objective-C**

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 40;
}
```

**In Swift:**

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat 
{   
    return 40
}
```

for more visit : [real world implementation](https://github.com/anuradhss/PickerViews/blob/master/PickerViews/Controllers/ViewControllerTwo.swift)

Comment: Is it possible to set different height for different row?

Comment: @ZhouHao haven't tried it and not sure :). I will try and let you know if I got a time. bit busy these days. sorry for that.