# pickerView different row height

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, reload

I have a pickerView with data loaded from website. I want to set the height for each row of pickerView.

Here is what i tried but seems that pickerView accept's only one value for all rows.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    var height: CGFloat = 40
    if categories.count != 0 {
        return heightForView((categories[component].valueForKey("name") as? String)!, font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: pickerFontSize!)!, width: pickerView.frame.width) + 10
    }
    return height + 10
}

func heightForView(text: String, font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

For the first time categories array is empty and rowHeightForComponent uses a constant value. But when I load data from Core Data I want my pickerView to reload itself with new componentHeight but it doesn't called when I wrote:

```
pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

Comment: Are you certain you set the delegate for your UIPickerView to your current class?

Comment: @halileohalilei `class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {` and `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // pickerView delegate n dataSource
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self`   is that right?

Comment: Have you also implemented the method `numberOfComponents:`?

Comment: @halileohalilei yes, I've implemented numberOfComponentsInPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent, titleForRow, viewForRow and rowHeightForComponent methods.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured that when you call `reloadAllComponents:` all of the delegate/dataSource methods get called **except** `rowHeightForComponent:`

I found a workaround that should resolve your problem. Each time you wish to set the height of the rows by calling `reloadAllComponents:`, reset the delegate for your `UIPickerView`. Something like this:

```
pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess picker view caches it’s size information at first time.
so with reloadAllComponents, you can update component’s data from data source and delegate but can not update row height.

---

workaround:

data source and delegate are set to nil until your data is prepared.
like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Setup UI...

    self.pickerView.dataSource = nil
    self.pickerView.delegate = nil
}
```

and data source and delegate are set properly after the data is ready.
like:

```
func updateUI() {

    // ...data is ready

    self.pickerView.dataSource = self // set data source
    self.pickerView.delegate = self // set delegate
    self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()

}
```

Comment: So what should I do if at the first time I haven't data and it loads some seconds after?

Answer (score 0):

`heightForView` is for specifying the height and `viewForRow` allows you to customize your rows. Thus, make your new height in the `heightForView` method, and make the customization of rows in the method `viewForRow` method instead of `heightForView` as you did right now.

And without specifying in the `heightForView` method, XCode can't change the height. Because it calls for the `heightForView`.

Lastly, reload your data as you got the data coming from the web.

Comment: in rowHeightForComponent I just calculate the height of my label and then return it, I didn't make any customizations there

Comment: If you want I can paste the whole code for better understanding

Comment: No I got confused. Maybe this link would help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397947/changing-uipickerview-row-height